# Download/execute data from PHP variable

Tags: php

I am trying to download PHP buffer output at the client's end. I am not interested in writing the output content to a file on the server and then allowing the download. I have checked my variable output by printing it on the browser. Since the buffer is supposed to be downloaded at the client's end as a file, where should I specify the file name?

```
<?php
  $file=$_POST['file'];
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/x-java-jnlp-file');  
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);
 ?>
```

~

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/readfile   you probably just need `echo $file`.

Comment: You also need to know about the `$_FILES` superglobal and [handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) using this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the "Content-Disposition" header:

```
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"' );
```

Full example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#example-4581

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this method

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Need more help  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php